# Blackberry 10 undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4

Tags: gcc, blackberry-10

On Blackberry 10 using C++ I am getting the following link errors

undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4 
   undefined reference to __sync_fetch_and_sub_4
   undefined reference to`__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_4

Anyone know which library I am missing. The Momentics IDE is using GCC 4.6.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wild stab in the dark but is it the 'math' library which can be added by including `LIBS += -lm` in your `.pro` file.